# Help identifying this component marked 'R5E 474'

Tags: identification

Repairing a vent window motor as the assembly is NLA. The small DC electric motor here lays in a tray and plugs into two terminals which are bridged by a small component which is tan/brown.

Two sets of letters/numbers on it R5E with 474 underneath. Also MBO with 922 underneath.

Searching the web doesn't give me any easy answers, so hoping someone can point me in the right direction so I can replace this component.

[image: close up]
<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siey7.jpg</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be a 0.47 uF Axial Multilayer Ceramic Capacitor (or rather, half of one).

The number code "474" tells us the capacity, similarly to the colour rings, and based on the [E series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) (most commonly E6):

- The first two digits are for the mantissa, \$47\$.
- The third digit is for the exponent, \$10^4 = 10,000\$.
- The unit is picofarad.

So this is \$47 * 10,000 pF = 470 nF = 0.47 \mu F\$.

Comment: That’s entirely plausible.  It doesn’t say anything about the voltage rating though, which is estimate by the size might be 10 to 50V.  A replacement part would need a voltage rating if at least what’s being used to drive the motor, it doesn’t do any harm to go higher.  The purpose of the capacitor is to reduce electrical noise and possibly to extend the life of the motor and/or whatever switches it.  Also check though whether some other failure has caused this, e.g. excessive voltage to the motor.

Comment: You are correct. Identified by a member of the Chrysler minivan forum. I applied 12v via alligator clips from a small 12 battery., left connected for approx 30 seconds, causing the damage I am guessing. New one from mouser installed with new motor reinstalled. works perfectly.